# bash terminal only updates after command execution

Tags: linux, bash

I have this function in my .bashrc to set the terminal's title:

```
function set-title(){
    if [[ -z "$ORIG" ]]; then
        ORIG="$PS1"
    fi
    TITLE="\[\e]2;$*\a\]"
    PS1="${ORIG}${TITLE}"
}
```

If then, in the same .bashrc, I create another function that uses set-title before a command execution, the title is not updated until the command ends, and this is a problem if the command needs to be running for a long time because then the title is never set. For example in:

```
function start_server(){
   set-title SERVER
   my_server -d    
}
```

The terminal title is not updated until I kill my_server.

Is there any way to make the set-title function work updating the terminal before the command is executed?

Thanks

Comment: Why not call it on the first few lines of the script? Before calling other functions

Comment: Thanks @ChenA. for the answer, but set-title is called from several functions inside .bashrc, not from an external script. I made some help functions in .bashrc for several different tasks (set a sdk, start a server, run some daemons... etc) and I would like to set the title accordingly in each case

Comment: How about running the long command in the background with &?

Comment: Not really an option because some daemons need to read the standard input